# context.params.userId undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a firebase cloud function. I want to get the userId from the context.params but when I access it I get "UserID 1: undefined" in the function log.

Here is the code for the function:

```
exports.onTrxnCreate = functions.firestore.document('/trxns/{trxnId}').onCreate(async(snap, context) => {

    const userId = context.params.userId;
    console.log('UserID 1: ' + userId);
    /*const userId = snap.ref.parent.parent.Id; THIS DIDN'T WORK */
   

    console.log('A new transaction has been added');
    
    const getUserDeviceToken = await db.collection('device').doc(userId).get();

    const deviceTokens = getUserDeviceToken.data().deviceToken;
    console.log('DeviceID: ' + deviceTokens);
    
    if (deviceTokens == null) {
        return console.error('No device tokens found');
    }

    let title = "Transaction added";
    let body = "A new transaction has been added";

    const payload = {

        notification: { title: title, body: body},
        data: {click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK' }

    };

    const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceTokens, payload);

    if (response.error) {

        console.error("Error sending message: ", response.error);

    } else {

        return console.log("Message sent successfully!");

    };

    return Promise.all(console.log('End of function'));

});
```

How can I get the userId for this function?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the userId for this function?

I guess you mean the userId of the user that created the Firestore document that triggered the Cloud Function.

This is not possible by default with Cloud Functions triggered by Firestore. On the other hand, it is possible for the Realtime Database with the [`auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#optional-auth) property.

If you want to get the userId of the user that created the Firestore document you should either:

1. Save the user ID in the document itself and get it via `snap.data().userId;`, or
2. Use the userId as the Firestore document ID and then you can get it through the [`params`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#params) property since it is one of the values of the wildcards in the Firestore doc path.

So, in your case, it is normal that `context.params.userId` is undefined since there is no `userId` wildcard in the Firestore doc path.

Comment: Could you please show how your second suggestion would be implemented? is it ".doc("{userId}").get();"?

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec thank you for your response. It makes a lot of sense to me. I am new to mobile apps and Firebase so I will try this.

Comment: @devOP1 The second suggestion is to assign the userId to the ID of the Firestore document that is created and that triggers the Cloud Function. Then userId is used as a wildcard in the Firestore doc path when defining the Cloud Function. I.e. `exports.onTrxnCreate = functions.firestore.document('/trxns/{userId}').onCreate(async(snap, context) => {const userId = context.params.userId; ..});`. This may not be possible if, for example, several docs linked to the user are created in the `trxns` collection. then the first suggestion is the only way.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I was able to get the userId from the document using your suggestion. Now, I need your help in getting the deviceID. In the code above you can see I am trying to use getUserDeviceToken and the userId. Obviously, I am not using the userId correctly in the path to the document. How do I do that?

Comment: This is the line I am asking about:      const getUserDeviceToken = await db.collection('device').doc(userId).get();

Comment: Are you sure `userId` has the value you expect? How do you define `db`?